# MATLAB – Intersection of 3D objects during video analysis

Tags: matlab

I have videos of rodents in a transparent cylinder that use their front paws to touch the sides of the cylinder. It looks something like this:

[image]

The point of this test is to see how many times the rodent can touch the sides of the cylinder or with which paw it touches, left or right.

Recently, I found out that people use MATLAB to determine points of intersection between 2D figures, such as a sine wave and a linear function, but I am wondering if MATLAB can determine points of intersection between 3D objects, such as the rodent's paw and the side of the glass cylinder. Is this type of analysis possible in MATLAB?